# TreeMap Iterator behaviour not consistent upon removal

Tags: java

Today when tying to discover a bug I found the TreeMap iterator behavior a little strange when removing objects. In fact has I tested different uses, in a simple example:

```
    TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "1");
    map.put("2", "2");
    map.put("3", "3");
    map.put("4", "4");
    map.put("5", "5");

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Before "+entry.getKey());
        iterator.remove();
        System.out.println("After " +entry.getKey());
    }
```

the result is:

```
Before 1
After 1 
Before 2
After 2
Before 3
After 3
Before 4
After 4
Before 5
After 5
```

But if I change it to:

```
    TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "1");
    map.put("2", "2");
    map.put("3", "3");
    map.put("4", "4");
    map.put("5", "5");

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

            String key = "4";

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
        if(entry.getKey().equals(key)){
            iterator.remove();
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Then for key = 4 the result is 5 and for key = 5 the result is 5 due to the links being changed upon removal. But why are the behaviors different. JIT? Even if that is the answer, shouldn't they be uniform?

Comment: The code you've given will never print anything, as no entry has a key for "X". Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I guess X is a placeholder for either 3 or 4?

Comment: @home: Quite possibly - but it would be a lot easier to reproduce if the OP just gave us a complete program ready to compile and run...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: no question, I agree

Comment: For X=2 , the result is 3 ? Thats surprising ! I would think that this should be 2, just like for X=4 , it is 4.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I hope its better now. Sorry for the constant changes but I has trying to reproduce the exact problem as if key = "3" then it prints "3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question as to why this happens, the comment gives a hint

```
// If strictly internal, copy successor's element to p and then make p
// point to successor.
```

AFAIK, this is part of keeping the tree balanced.

What this means if you have only one child node (or none) the node itself is removed. If the node has two children, the node is replaced with its successor.

If you always remove from the start, that node is discarded which you can still use but it is not modified.  If you remove the right node from the middle of the tree, the entry is modified to balance the tree so using the entry after removing see the modified entry.

Answer (score 6):

See the Javadoc for [Map.Entry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) for `getValue()`:

> Returns the value corresponding to this entry. If the
>   mapping has been removed from the backing map (by the iterator's
>   remove operation), the results of this call are undefined.

The behaviour is undefined once you've removed the entry, hence that may explain why you are getting varying results.

NOTE: Another user, aix, posted a similar answer and I was going to comment on it, but it was deleted/removed for some reason.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this answer is correct, since I just noticed the OP was calling `getKey()` instead of `getValue()`.

EDIT 2: Thanks to Ed Staub for this: I think the general idea still holds, since the Javadoc for `Map.Entry` states:

> ... more formally, the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator, except through the setValue operation on the map entry.

Comment: but the code calls getKey() not getValue() , and the doc for getKey() does not say the same thing

Comment: A minor nit: Pedro is using getKey(), not getValue(), and the method javadocs for getKey() doesn't have the same caveat.  However, I think you're right anyway; in particular, the Map.Entry class doc says, more generally: `...the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator, except through the setValue operation on the map entry. `

Comment: @Bhaskar @EdStaub thanks for the information. Ed, I think you're right. In general the `Map.Entry` object probably can't be relied upon if the backing map has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't call this is a "strange" behaviour. It may just not be what you expected.

`TreeMap` internally implements a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal). When removing a node, the tree get's rebalanced (see `TreeMap.deleteEntry(Entry<K,V> p)`) and there are several cases how this reblanacing is done which depend on the current tree respectively which node gets removed.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but why does the Map.Entry Javadoc for the getValue() method says that the result is undefined? Shouldn't it say that the result depends on the implementation?

Comment: By declaring the result *undefined*, the API does not impose a specific behaviour to those who implement it. So for me it's just a synonym for *depends on the implementation*.